# Which part of hand is used to do a volleyball smash?

Tags: technique, volleyball

I have tried different hand formation and tried different positions of hand to hit the ball, but the smash either goes out of court or is very low powered.I just don't get how to hit it. So that its high powered and stays inside the court?

Comment: I'd guess the angle that you're hitting the ball at has more to do with bad placement (and how hard you hit it with power) than how your hand makes contact.

Comment: It happens every time the timing gets all messed  up . I was guessing what part of hand or how the volleball players use?

Comment: For reference, a Google search for hitting technique yielded no pages in the top 10 results that even mention the hand; good hitting is all in the footwork and arm swing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spiking in volleyball is much more about timing and approach than hand placement.  I would first focus on learning when to jump and swing in regard to the set and flight of the ball.  If you can't contact the ball at the right time, then it doesn't really matter what you hit it with.  Personally, after practicing approach and swing, the "hitting" aspect seemed to just fall into place, but I know that's not really an acceptable answer to your question.

If you check out [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Spike-a-Volleyball) site, it gives a step-by-step approach of how to spike a volleyball.  For the most part, I agree with everything that it suggests.  Step 8 & 9 instruct:

> (8) ...hit the ball, contacting the upper half of the ball **with the heel of your open hand** at the very top of your swing
>
> (9) Snap your wrist downward to impart topspin and direct the ball down into your opponent's court **while spreading your fingers**

*(emphasis added)*

If you feel like you've already got your approach down, try these suggestions, I think they'll work for you.

Answer (score -2):

I try to get the ball at the bottom of my middle finger as I feel that gives me absolute full palm contact with the ball and snap my wrist down at initial contact and it seems to work for me.